# Xubuntu random freezing

Tags: freeze

I have problems with random freeze in Xubuntu 18.04 and 19.10. The sound still works but mouse stopped working and i need to restart my computer. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot solve your problem.  But, you can save some time by putting
`setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp` in /etc/profile.  Then, logout and login.

The next time you have a freeze, restart the desktop by entering Ctrl-Alt-Backspace, assuming your X is not frozen.